# How to Implement Video Ads like YouTube and Netflix that shows before playing the actual video

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, web, video, youtube

**I am trying to make a video streaming site programmed in

PHP or ASP.NET

I am trying to recreate the senerio that YouTube show.
ie. When someone clicks the video it shows a video ad in my video player.
**

Problem: I want to show then the video promotion ad without actually adding the video to all 20k+ videos and let there be 4 video promo named 1/2/3/4.mp4 respectively so it should be random that the video is played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use [WebM byte stream format](https://www.w3.org/2013/12/byte-stream-format-registry/webm-byte-stream-format.html) which makes it easy for you to have the browser download the video in chunks (*these are called WebM clusters*). As the browser downloads one chunk it sends back a token to the server requesting the next chunk (*based on timestamps in the video stream*). The server can then make the determination to stop sending the video stream of the main feature and instead send a video stream for the advertisement. It will normally update the browser with new tokens upon each request to ensure that tokens can't be reused to obtain new chunks without the server first making the determination if an advertisement should be played mid-stream or not. This same mechanism is what most video streaming sites use to control when ads can be played during the video stream.

> [WebM](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/) is a digital multimedia container file format promoted by the open-source WebM Project. It comprises a subset of the Matroska multimedia container format.

---

So to walk through a practical example of this technique let's assume we have a video file that's 10 minutes long. What we aim to do is chop up the video into smaller chunks (let's say about 30 seconds each), but only in a logical way. The video file remains intact physically. When the page is first loaded the server will supply a non-reusable token (like a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)) that can be used to retrieve the first chunk of the video (*the first 30 seconds*). So the browser fires off an AJAX request along with the token and the server will respond with a 30 second chunk of the video and a renewed token. This process will recur over and over again until we reach the end of the video. If at any time the server decides we need to show an ad then instead of sending along the next 30 seconds of video we send along instead the ad. To the end-user it appears as though the video and ad are all playing in the same video.

The way the server is keeping track of how much of the video the user has watched is based on the tokens the user sends back in the next request. This is how you can arbitrarily place ads in the video based on video length.

Answer (score 1):

Using WebM is a option but you can make it like a refresh timer that selects the a random no.

Example ( for starter)

$a = (url of the video)
$b = generate random no. (1-4)  //i didn't add. Any code

Now when the page let www.example.com

Create a timer of about the time of the video then play the video after which die() the connection and play the video link with the end of timer with header()

I am not good at explaning but it should work